# How can I get a list of commands used for navigating in the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, shell

In the terminal, what should I type to show a list consisting of command items such as these:

- `ls`: show direcrtory
- `cd`: move to directory

… and so on.

What command can you use to display this list?

Comment: Technically, you don't navigate the terminal, you navigate in a [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)) that's running inside the terminal. Therefore, you need to look for your shell's built-in commands. The default shell on OS X is [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a complete list of **every** command on your Linux system, press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key and enter <kbd>y</kbd> to the question. All your commands will be gracefully displayed.

If you are looking for help on a particular command, use this syntax: `man command-name`. Example: `man ls` will give you the manual for the [ls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls) command.

Answer (score 3):

There are many 'cheat-sheets' and reference pages available online which contain Linux commands and their descriptions - which can be saved and revisited - if you're looking for a list of the main Linux/Unix commands, what they are, etc.

- [Unix/Linux Command Line Reference](http://files.fosswire.com/2007/08/fwunixref.pdf) (PDF)
- [The 'One Page Linux Manual'](http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/QRC/The%20One%20Page%20Linux%20Manual.pdf) (PDF)
- [Unix Toolbox](http://cb.vu/unixtoolbox.xhtml) (HTML)
- [TB Unix Sheet](http://www.rain.org/~mkummel/unix.html) (HTML)

There's also (as mentioned in another answer) the `man` pages, available online [here](http://www.linuxmanpages.com) or in your terminal environment and the O'Reilly Command Directory [here](http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/).

([Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' answer](https://superuser.com/questions/457736/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-commands-used-for-navigating-in-the-terminal/457739#457739) relates to viewing commands and their descriptions outside of the actual terminal window, online in a simplified manner and are for reference.)

Answer (score 2):

You generally don't use any. You use [RUTE](http://rute.2038bug.com/index.html.gz) to learn them, and `man` to learn about them. And while RUTE is primarily Linux-oriented, 80+% is applicable to OS X.

Comment: The problem with `man` is that you need to know what the command is called. If you sort of know what you want to do but don't know the command you can use `apropos` to find it. Though it can be a bit verbose in it's output as it not only lists commands.